# 3d surface plot with vectors in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

Could you please help me with the following issue: I would like to 3d plot 3 vectors in MATLAB. I know that it translates into points in a 3d space, but is there a way to obtain actually the surface? I tried similar approaches found in different answers, but they don't seem to work for my data, i.e. I obtain an empty graph. Thanks a lot! Below the codes I tried:

```
%Method 1:   
[X2,Y2]=meshgrid(a1,a2);
Z2=griddata(a1,a2,z,X2,Y2);
surf(a1,a2,Z2); % I obtain an empty graph in this case

%Method 2:
trisurf(delaunay(a1,a2),a1,a2,z) %In this case I obtain a graph but it seems unrealistic

%Method 3: using scatter3, I obtain a line, but I would like to have a surface
scatter3(a1,a2,z)
```

a1 and a2 are 1x100 vectors with values in (0,1) and z is a complicated function of these two vectors, also having dimension 1x100.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

```
a1 = [0.05  0.06   0.07 0.08    0.09    0.1 ...]
a2 = [0.9   0.89   0.88   0.87  0.86   0.85 ...]
z = [-0.0009 -0.0011 -0.0012    -0.0014 -0.0016 -0.0017 ...]
```

Comment: Try `surf(X2,Y2,Z2)`. It shouldn't be empty unless all your values are `NaN`.

Comment: I still obtain an empty plot. X2 and Y2 are 100x100, repeating the values in a1 and a2, and my Z2 has values only on the diagonal, and off diagonal elements are NaN. Can it be because the values in Z2 are similar and close to 0?

Comment: No, a NaN from `griddata` means that those points are outside the convex hull of the input points, or your data (`z`) have NaNs to begin with. OK, I think I see the problem: if your `a1-a2` pairs form a *line*, you can't interpolate with griddata, because that would be *extra*polation, which griddata doesn't do. But that's OK: you *can't* reconstruct data on a line to guess what's on a rectangle.

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you provided us with samples for `a1`, `a2` and `z`...

Comment: This is exactly the case, my a1-a2 pairs form a line. Is there a way to still construct a surface?

Comment: @Astrid no. I mean, there could be some interpolators which extrapolate for you, but the result from that would be meaningless. If you're *absolutely sure* about the underlying function, and it's simple enough, you could maybe try fitting a 2d surface to it, but I wouldn't keep your hopes up. There's just too much information missing in my layman's opinion.

Comment: @Andras, thanks a lot for your reply.